# Can I compile Ming for PHP/Windows?

Tags: php, flash

Where can I find instructions for compiling Ming? Google is confused and thinks I am looking for pages about MinGW (the C++ lib for Windows) when in fact I want this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ming.php (a PHP lib for creating SWF files)

I currently have Wamp Server installed. I checked the option `php_ming`, but Ming still did not work. I finally found out that even though Wamp is adding the right line to the php.ini file, the actual file it refers to "php_ming.dll" does not exist on my computer.

It also does not appear to exist on the Internet (at least not on any safe looking website). So, apparently, I must compile it from scratch. Compiling in C is very difficult for me, because I do not understand why so many different types of files and configuration options are required, which files to get, where to get them, and where to put them.

I get DOT C files (programs) and DOT H files (includes), but I quickly get lost with DOT O files, "linker" files, command line options - and all the specifics which must be exactly right for any compile to work. For this reason, I am looking for instructions on how to compile Ming for PHP/Windows. Where can I find this?

Comment: [You can't](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ming.install.php).

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Are you saying there is no valid place for a question about Ming anywhere on the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: It's not that there's no place, I'm saying that with current version of that library you can't produce a .dll file for windows php build. The documentation says so and quickly checking the source - there are no windows specific definitions or macros, nor does the official website say anything about using it in windows environment. Running a compiler under windows doesn't mean you can compile any C code and  have it work there. That just means you can't use that library under windows.

Comment: Questions asking about where you can ask a question belong on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), but I am pretty sure that since this is something one would use in programming, it is okay here. I've modified the question to reflect the actual question, rather than the question about the question `;-)`.

Comment: Thanks - that was much more helpful. However, from the Official Ming website: "Releases through to 0.3.0 progressed slowly, though the new 0.4.0 release has picked up speed, become more reliable, and supports Win32 much better" -- Win32 support is Windows is it not? http://www.libming.org/

Comment: [This page](http://www.gazbming.com/howto.html) suggests that Xampp contains the binaries you need. Try that?

Comment: @halfer I tried that - XAMPP does not appear to contain any Ming binaries. I don't know what the guy was thinking - I also downloaded the PHP Windows binaries - lots of DLL extensions are packaged, but no Ming is packaged. Perhaps I am taking the wrong approach to generating SWF files - I thought Ming was the predominate package - perhaps someone knows what the best package to generate SWF files on Windows is (preferably from PHP).

Comment: yes I can confirm that xampp contained ming but does not anymore. It dropped support something between version 1.7.4 and 1.7.7. old versions: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/

Comment: I think 1.7.4 is the last version with ming support because from 1.7.5 on are VC9 versions.

Comment: @user353885 if you do not need dynamic swf files try [flex-sdk](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html). Just install the great editor [flashdevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) and it will download and install the sdk for you..

Comment: @bitWorking: do you know if this module can be compiled with VC9, or did Xampp drop it because that was not possible?

Comment: I do not know a VC9 version. You could try to compile your own: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/ming/branches/PHP_5_3/

Comment: I was able to find the DLL module in version 1.7.3, however, apparently the DLL needs resources in other DLLs that are part of the installation. So, the DLL in this package is useless by itself - however, I installed the entire 1.7.3 package and Ming finally does work. Having 2 web-servers is not the optimal solution (especially one of them being rather old), but I am glad I at least have a way to generate SWF. Thanks - nice find!

Comment: @bitWorking Thanks for the tip - I installed FlashDevelop, but I see nothing about Flex SDK - http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/About/ - It appears to be some sort of web app framework - Wikipedia indicates Flex SDK can in fact make SWF files via a command line program called MXMLC, but this does not come with FlashDevelop. Just curious - where does flash generation come into play?

Comment: @user353885 my flashdevelop version installed the flex sdk automatically. but you can configure it manually. just download the sdk and add the path under Tools->Program Settings->AS3Context->Installed Flex SDKs. Now you can create a new AS2/3(FLash) or MXML(Flex) Project and compile it to a swf file.

Comment: @bitWorking I installed FD earlier today and was able to generate SWF files by building an AS3 project - however, I quickly learned that the dynamic Flash content must be specified by ActionScript - all I am trying to do is generate SWF files with "X" number of frames, where each frame has text fields with custom text content in the Arial Black font - long story short, I am told ActionScript cannot add frames - therefore, it seems I cannot generate a SWF file with multiple frames from FD using the method you mention. =/